# Node.js. Error: module is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a main file -- index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');

var demo = require('demo');

// This app will only respond requests to the '/scrape' URL at port 3000.
app.get('/scrape', function (req, res) {
    var url = "http://www.l.com";

    request(url, function (error, response, html) { // two parameters: an URL and a callback
        if (!error) {
            demo(html);
        }
    });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

and my module is demo.js:

```
module.exports = function (html) {
    ....

    return JSON.stringify(json);
}
```

The error is :

**TypeError: demo is not a function**

I am new to node.js, i would like to know why this didn't work. Maybe i dont understand the real principle of module?
Thank you for answer me first.

Comment: Where in your code is demo?

Comment: module.exports.demo = function(html){... } ?

Comment: Are the `require("leboncoin")` statement and subsequent function call causing the problem? Because you don't require "demo.js" at all in the code given here and everything else should work. If so, have you looked at the example code [here](https://github.com/moul/node-leboncoin/tree/master/examples)?

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your 3 answers. I made 2 mistakes, first is var leboncoin = require('leboncoin'); i should write var leboncoin = require('./demo').

Comment: the path of the module is very important, and the name of it must the same of the module, and wihout ".js"

Comment: I solved the problem, i wrote a comment to this kind of problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the other freshers who use module in node.js for the first time.

first, made a new module called **the name of your module.js**
Second, it is not necessary to do "
`npm install demo --save`", if you want, it is also okay.
Third, in the main js which u want to call this module, focus on the **name** and the **path** of the module, you should write `var anyName = require('the name of your module');`, if they are in the same directory, you should write like this: var anyName = require('./the name of your module');

Answer (score 0):

You're not exporting your module properly. It should be:

```
exports.demo = function ....
```

Comment: sorry, but i dont think is the problem of export

Comment: @LeylaLee Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to include your demo module in index.js:
`var demo = require('./demo.js');`